# Rails 4.1 jQuery Masonry doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

I've tried applying the One Month Rails tutorial to my rails 4.1 application. Though a lot of it works perfectly, the part about jQuery Masonry doesn't.
I've built an app with a blogging function, which I've called Articles. I have made an Articles Overview page, where I would like to make an articles overview in a Pinterest-like style, so with a picture, small piece of text, title and a 'Read more' button, linking to the whole article.
The page looks like this:

```
#app/views/articles/overview.html.erb

<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>
        Articles
    </h1>
    <p>
        Text.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="articles" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
            <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
        <%= link_to article_path(article) do %>
          <%= image_tag article.image_url(:medium).to_s, class: "img-responsive" %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= article.summary %><br>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <%= link_to 'Read more', article_path(article) %> 
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
             | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> | 
              <%= link_to 'Delete', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My layout page looks like this:

```
#app/views/layouts/articles.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
          <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</html>
```

The CSS I've added for the page is:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/articles.css.scss

#articles {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've included

> *= require 'masonry/transitions'

in my application.css file and

> //= require masonry/jquery.masonry

in my application.js file.

Additionally, my articles.js.coffee file looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#articles').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#articles').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box',
      isFitWidth: true
```

Also, I've installed the masonry-rails and jquery-turbolinks gems via bundler.

Even though it should work, it doesn't: instead of displaying the articles pinterest-like, it displays them in a list:

[image]

Furthermore, Google Chrome displays the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm certainly no expert, so I suppose it'll be something stupid, but I can't figure it out, even after googling for days and reading lots of StackOverflow questions about it. Thanks for all the help in advance!!

Comment: The easiest way is to check the CSS/HTML directly using developer extension. As for example what will be the output if you remove class="box panel panel-default" from the div? Are you using bootstrap ? and btw it would be easier to create partial and render it directly like render @articles, in this case you will need to move the html to _article.html.erb.

Comment: Yes @EkiEqbal I am using bootstrap. I tried removing the "box panel panel-default" class, but that didn't work. I have managed to make it work somehow, by changing my articles.js.coffee file to
--------

  $(document).ready ($) ->
  $container = $("#articles")
  setTimeout (->
    
    # initialize
    $container.masonry
      columnWidth: 100
      itemSelector: ".box"

    return
  ), 200
  return

----------

which did fix the problem somehow, but in production mode it doesn't work. I've tried so many things I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have imagesLoaded script included in your application. otherwsise it wont work

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

the link to imageLoaded script.